# pandas print data frame from dict: max rows not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, display

I am using the following code to print Dataframes from dicts. It prints all rows of my column.

Why doesn't the `.max_rows` setting take effect?

This seems to be because I am using `to_string`. Without to string, the settings take effect, but I will have indices.

I don't want indices, and I want only a couple rows.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.max_rows = 5
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 5)

result_dict = {"long_col": [0]*100}

result_frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result_dict)

print(result_frame.to_string(index=True, justify='left'))
```

Comment: `pd.options` are only options for pandas objects... and after `to_string` this is just a python `str` object. Check `type(result_frame)` and `type(result_frame.to_string(index=True, justify='left'))`

Comment: Thanks, that was an acceptable answer. now, I did an edit on the question, since I need `.to_string` to hide the indices

Comment: What about just printing the head: `print(result_frame.head().to_string(index=True, justify='left'))` ?

Comment: yeah, is an idea. But just cutting of the rest might make someone think there isn't more

Comment: Starting to get a bit hacky, but could just tack on an ellipsis: `print(result_frame.head().to_string(index=True, justify='left'), '...', sep='\n')`